# How can Vue js load image from /dist/ folder when it does not exist?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

So I'm trying to learn Vue.js + webpack and initated a project by following these steps:

```
f:www\> npm install -g vue-cli
f:www\> vue init webpack-simple my-project
f:www\> cd my-project
f:www\> npm install
f:www\> npm run dev
```

The default page runs on `http://localhost:8080/`.

Now, in `webpack.config.js`file I have the following lines:

```
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
```

and in the `index.html` we find the following line  `<script src="/dist/main.js"></script>`

At this point I thought Webpack was a bit like Gulp in that it compiles src files and puts them in the /dist/ folder.

But Webpack never creates the /dist/ folder.

1. How can the Vue logo be loaded from `<img src="/dist/logo.png?82b9c7a5a3f405032b1db71a25f67021">` when /dist/ folder does not exist?
2. Why is main.js not created?

**webpack.config.js** (short version)

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map';
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Comment: try changing `path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),` to `path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),`

Comment: Same outcome. A similar question suggested  to chage `publicPath: '/dist/',` to `publicPath: './dist',`. But it still doesn't explain how the logo seemingly is loaded from /dist/ folder.

Comment: Not sure what `publicPath` is for but if you're using node + express you can `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));` to serve up static files, and then remove out the `publicPath`.... not sure about the logo though

Comment: I'm just running out ofthe box setup with `vue init webpack-simple`. So at the moment I'm not using express - but I will later. I'm just trying to understand how this works.

Answer (score 0):

So after some more googling, I found [this turorial](https://vegibit.com/vue-cli-webpack-simple-tutorial/) that explains the entire `webpack-simple` setup.

Here is the section regarding the /dist/ folder:

> **npm run build**
>   Right now we are simply using **npm run dev** to work with and test out an
>   installation of the Vue Cli tool. This is great
>   for testing in the local environment, but what about if you actually
>   want to publish your application to the web? In this case you will
>   instead run **npm run build**. This will build your application for
>   production and you’ll see a new **/dist/** folder which contains the
>   finished bundle.

So during development, the files are placed in a chached / temp location (not sure where)